# In the field of Probabilistic Databases, how can one compute the lineage and the safeness of a boolean query over a tuple-independent table?

Tags: database-theory

Suppose we have a *tuple-independent database* (TID) named **D** and we have to evaluate if a boolean query **Q(D)** is *safe* or *not safe* using the *intensional query evaluation* approach. I suppose we have to compute the lineage of Q and reason with that, but I am not quite sure of how to do it. How can one compute the lineage of a boolean query **Q** over a probabilistic database **D** and use that to evaluate the *safeness* of the query?